# How to exclude moment locales from angular build?

Tags: angular, angular2-moment

In my angular 5 application, when I create build using

```
ng build --prod --sm
```

and open source map explorer, moment takes lot of space in the main.js file. I have found all the locales gets loaded when I use

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

I have used material-moment-adapter to some functionality in the application that requires the moment package also.

I have created the application using angular-cli. I have found many links that excludes locales using settings in webpack.config.js
Is there any way to exclude locales using angular-cli ?

Comment: You can either use lazy loading or switch to the native module for material. I would recommend the second option.

Comment: https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment

Comment: can you please provide some example for material native module?

Comment: I have used moment-mini . It worked

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This article describe good solution:
https://medium.jonasbandi.net/angular-cli-and-moment-js-a-recipe-for-disaster-and-how-to-fix-it-163a79180173

Briefly:

1. `ng add ngx-build-plus`
2. Add a file webpack.extra.js in the root of your project:

   ```
   const webpack = require('webpack');
   module.exports = {
       plugins: [
           new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   npm run build --prod --extra-webpack-config webpack.extra.js
   ```

**Warning**
moment.js has been deprecated officially
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ (try use day.js or luxon)

Comment: when i use this answer the compiler gives this error An unhandled exception occurred: Project 'webpack.extra.js' does not exist.

Comment: and when I change npm run build with ng build the compiler gives this error: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '/Users/test/Desktop/projects/shb2c/webpack.extra.js'
Require stack:

Comment: Check step 2: ADD/CREATE webpack.extra.js in the root of your project

Comment: moment.js deprecated ?

Comment: giving me an error: ``` Unknown option: '--extra-webpack-config'
Unknown option: 'webpack.extra.js' ```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use any third party libraries the simplest way to do this is to add the following in **compilerOptions** of your **tsconfig.json** file

```
"paths": {
  "moment": [
    "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I was not able to make it work with this solution if moment-timezone is used.

Comment: this doesnt provide moment directive

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
However I'm getting `Could not find a declaration file for module 'moment'.` error with this way. 
Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone on angular 12 or latest

This does not work for me

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ]
}
```

However this does

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
      resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
      contextRegExp: /moment$/
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution in this Angular Issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6137#issuecomment-387708972

Add a custom path with the name "moment" so it is by default resolved to the JS file you want:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "moment": [
        "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 12, I did the following:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular-builders/custom-webpack
```

to allow using a custom webpack configuration.

```
npm i --save-dev moment-locales-webpack-plugin
npm i --save-dev moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin
```

Then modify your `angular.json` as follows:

```
    ...
    "architect": {
        "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
                "options": {
                    "customWebpackConfig": {
                        "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
                    },
                    ...
```

and in the `extra-webpack.config.js` file:

```
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const MomentTimezoneDataPlugin = require('moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: ['en-ie']
        }),
        new MomentTimezoneDataPlugin({
            matchZones: /Europe\/(Belfast|London|Paris|Athens)/,
            startYear: 1950,
            endYear: 2050,
        }),
    ]
};
```

Modify the above options as needed, of course. This gives you far better control on which exact locales and timezones to include, as opposed to the regular expression that I see in some other answers.

Answer (score 0):

the solutions above didn't work for me because they address the wrong path (don't use ../ ) in the tsconfig.app.json

```
{
...
   "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
        "moment": [
          "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Works for me in Angular 12.2.X. The changes must be done in the tsconfig.app.json, than also the type information of your IDE will work.
[image]

[image]

Don't change it in the tsconfig.json or your IDE will lose type information.
[image]

This fix the usage in the app as in the lib. I used source-map-explorer to verify it.

```
ng build --sourceMap=true --namedChunks=true --configuration production && source-map-explorer dist/**/*.js
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with **momentjs** library and solve it as below:

The main purpose of this answer is not to use **IgnorePlugin** for ignoring the library but I use **ContextReplacementPlugin** to tell the compiler which locale files I want to use in this project.

1. Do all of the configurations mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72423671/6666348
2. Then in your webpack.config.js file write this:

   ```
   const webpack = require("webpack");

   module.exports = {
       plugins: [
           new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /(en|fr)$/)
       ]
   };
   ```

This configuration will add only **en** and **fr** locale in your application dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use moment-mini-ts instead of moment

```
npm i moment-mini-ts

import * as moment from 'moment-mini-ts'
```

Don’t forget to uninstall moment

```
npm uninstall moment
```

I’m using angular 9