# Remove moment from chartjs in angular app

Tags: angular, webpack, chart.js, angular-cli, ng2-charts

I am using [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) in my project, it is basically just a wrapper over [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) so I have to install `chart.js` as well. According to the chart.js docs, [moment is included by default](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html) in the build, and must be excluded by configuring webpack. Is there a way to configure the build in an angular application? Or some other way to exclude moment? Note, I am not using chart.js directly, it is used by the `ng2-charts` lib.

Comment: check this out .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851277/how-to-exclude-moment-locales-from-angular-build

Comment: I am puzzled about the down vote: this is a perfectly good question. And not about slimming down the moment bundle by removing locales, but about removing `moment.js` completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the upcomming release (V3) of the `ng2-charts` lib which uses Chart.js V3 it is not pressent anymore by default.

According to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc) of chart.js itself you can remove moment like so:

```js
// Webpack
{
    externals: {
        moment: 'moment'
    }
}

// Rollup
{
    external: ['moment']
}
```